# trying open links from an array in coffeescript and getting error

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Just started using coffeescript in a static site generator and I'm getting an error with a simple script. I'm trying to open several links in a new window when a button is clicked, and then after a period of time, the windows will close.

I'm getting a

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of null

Here is the HTML:

```
<a id="download-button" class="btn-large">Open Links</a>
```

And here is the coffeescript

```
 $('a#download-button').on "click", ->

    urlList = [
      'http://www.google.com'
      'http://www.msn.com'
      'http://www.yahoo.com'
    ]

    wnd = undefined
    curIndex = 0

    openWindow = ->
      wnd = window.open(urlList[curIndex], '', '')
      setTimeout (->
        wnd.close()
        curIndex++
        if curIndex < urlList.length
          openWindow()
        return
      ), 2000
      return

    openWindow()
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`window.open` can return `null` if the call fails. This can be caught with `window?.open(url)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open